Where to find iPad 13-inch display?
I am currently trying to upload my app to the App Store, but I’ve encountered an issue where it requires screenshots for an iPad with a 13-inch display. As far as I can tell, this size is only available for the latest iPad Air, and I haven't been able to find a simulator for it in Xcode.
My Xcode version is 15.0. I checked the release notes for version 15.4, but I didn't see any mention of updates that include a 13-inch iPad display simulator.
I have screenshots for the 12.9-inch iPad and I can upload these to the 13-inch slot, but I'm unsure if these will be acceptable for the app review process.
Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

See Screenshot specifications: the resolution of 12.9 inch is the same as 13 inch and it works to upload the same screenshots to both.

@BenzyNeez your comment pointed me in the right direction. However, not all 12.9 inches because the iPad Pro 2nd Generation is not listed under the 13" Display. Thanks for your comment

Update to Xcode 15.4 and you'll find the new iPad 13" and 11" simulators.

i'm using Xcode Version 16.0  and i still cant find it

You may need to add them through the Devices and Simulators window in Xcode.
